# Python Storing a Binary Data in File on disk

Tags: python, caching

Wondering what would be a good choice to store a binary data in file on a disk.
Great if it would be a built-in Python module since I would like to keep it all stock.
A random access to a written data could be a plus but it's not required. For this implementation I would rather go for a simplicity and speed. 
What I am looking for: save it now - get it later. Thanks in advance!

EDITED:

Found a problem why cPickle was erroring out. In one of the classes I have declared self.os=os And it appears self.os is not something cPickle likes... A bit later I found that cPickle doesn't accept PyQT objects if they (PyQT class instances) are given as a class's attributes (in case you dump a list of some_class instances).

An example below if run replicates the same error:

```
import cPickle
import os

class MyClass(object):
    """docstring for MyClass"""
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
        self.os=os         

data=MyClass("Hello World")    

file_name='dampData.data'

out_file = open(file_name, 'wb')
cPickle.dump(data, out_file)
out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend cPickle - it is also built-in and significantly faster than pickle (in most cases).

example:

```
import cPickle

out_file = open(file_name, 'w')
cPickle.dump(data, out_file)
out_file.close()

in_file = open(file_name, 'r')
data = cPickle.load(in_file)
in_file .close()
```

From the official documentation of **pickle**:

> The pickle module has an optimized cousin called the cPickle module.
>   As its name implies, cPickle is written in C, so it can be up to 1000 times faster than pickle.

Comment: While dampening a binary data (which is an instance of the class) cPickle gives this Error:                                                                    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__    TypeError: can't pickle module objects

Comment: Which class are you dumping? 
have you tried:
out_file = open(file_name, 'wb')
in_file = open(file_name, 'rb')
?

Comment: Ive jist tried 'wb' flag instead of just 'w' while writing to a file. Unfortunately it did not fix the problem. cPickle refuses to dump. I have managed to make it dump a simple string variable. I opened a dump file made by cPickle and its content appeared to be a human readable. Are you sure cPickle works with a binary form?

Comment: What class is the object you dump?

Comment: Please see a response I appended to an original posting.

Comment: If you chose to use cPickle it would be appropriate to accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) and [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) modules!

Comment: pickle complains it cannot dump a class's instance object        TypeError: can't pickle module objects

Comment: @Sputnix seems that you pickling pickle module itself somehow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790828/python-cant-pickle-module-objects-error

Comment: Please see a response I appended to an original posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal python functions to read/write binary. Add a 'b' to the mode if on Windows:

```
f = open('workfile', 'wb') # opens a file for writing in binary mode
```

If you're using python 3, then you may need to do a little more work with string encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Reading and Writing Files:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

You may also want to serialize your data so its easier to work with

http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 0):

It's builtin.

```
f = open("somefile.zip", "rb")
g = open("thecopy.zip", "wb")

while True:
    buf = f.read(1024)
    if len(buf) == 0:
         break
    g.write(buf)

f.close()
g.close()
```

http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/files.html