# how to fix 'TypeError: can't pickle module objects' during multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to implement multiprocessing, but I am having difficulties accessing information from the object **scans** that I'm passing through the pool.map() function

Before multiprocessing (this works perfectly):

```
for sc in scans:
    my_file = scans[sc].resources['DICOM'].files[0]
```

After multiprocessing (does not work, error shown below):

```
def process(x):
    my_file = x.resources['DICOM'].files[0] 

def another_method():
    ...                
    pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
    pool.map(process, [scans[sc] for sc in scans])

another_method()
```

The error I am getting with 'After multiprocessing' code:

```
---> 24         pool.map(process, [scans[sc] for sc in scans])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    266         in a list that is returned.
    267         '''
--> 268         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    269 
    270     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    655             return self._value
    656         else:
--> 657             raise self._value
    658 
    659     def _set(self, i, obj):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in _handle_tasks(taskqueue, put, outqueue, pool, cache)
    429                         break
    430                     try:
--> 431                         put(task)
    432                     except Exception as e:
    433                         job, idx = task[:2]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py in send(self, obj)
    204         self._check_closed()
    205         self._check_writable()
--> 206         self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
    207 
    208     def recv_bytes(self, maxlength=None):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py in dumps(cls, obj, protocol)
     49     def dumps(cls, obj, protocol=None):
     50         buf = io.BytesIO()
---> 51         cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
     52         return buf.getbuffer()
     53 

TypeError: can't pickle module objects
```

Comment: What is `data_inputs`? First of all you don't need to declare it as global. Your code as above should work fine. Assuming it's a dict, you can just pass its values instead : `pool.map(process_scan, data_inputs.values())`

Comment: @Tomerikoo I just clarified this in my post. Also, when I try to run the line of code you suggested, I get this error: `TypeError: can't pickle module objects`

Comment: I said assuming it's a dict... I am not familiar with `XNATListing` objects... But as I said, your code should just work. There is no need to declare variables as globals for reading...

Comment: @Tomerikoo sorry, i forgot to mention that the pool calls are made from another method! (edited the post)

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that `data_inputs` is still accessible... I don't understand what's wrong with it, are you getting an error? No output? As I said the code should just work. Unless I'm missing something because there is no [mre]

Comment: @Tomerikoo 'data_inputs' is a local value in another_method(). If I try to run the code, it will say `NameError: name 'data_inputs' is not defined` when it tries to run the code in process_scan()

Comment: Your question doesn't reflect that... You should always post a [mre]. Anyway, you can probably change `map` to [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) to solve your problem...

Comment: But again that seems unnecesary as you're only using `data_inputs` only to access it with `sc`. Why not just `pool.map(process_scan, [data_inputs[sc] for sc in data_inputs])` And then your `process_scan` can be `def process_scan(val):
my_file = val.resources['DICOM'].files[0]`

Comment: @Tomerikoo your solution makes sense to me, but when I try to run it, it gives me a `TypeError: can't pickle module objects` error (full error pasted in the post)

Comment: Your question became a little messy. Please [edit] it according to [ask] with a proper [mre] so it is possible to help you

Comment: @Tomerikoo fixed, hope it's more clear now!

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux? I believe your program might be related to the missing `__main__` guard.  Go over [the guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) and see if it helps you, Basically you need to have the `pool` call protected under the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard. Otherwise all your processes are calling their own child processes which breaks the system

Comment: @Tomerikoo I am running on mac. I have also tried surrounding the pool commands with an 'if' condition, but it will skip the content inside of the if condition. Also, another_method() happens to be called during an __init__() of an object_1, which is created by another method in an object_2, and object_2 is created within an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard

Comment: It sounds like you complicated things too much, and again, still haven't provided a [mre]. I suggest you try to simplify things and only run multiprocessing from the main level of your progrma

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the full data structure, but this might help. Multiprocessing is kinda sensible to objects... some object can't be pickled like file objects.
[Python: can't pickle module objects error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790828/python-cant-pickle-module-objects-error)

If you need only the file name use that in the map function instead of process

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but I got around this issue by changing a little bit the for loop.

```
def process(i_x):
    x = scans[i_x]
    my_file = x.resources['DICOM'].files[0] 

def another_method():
    ...      
    scans = ...      
    pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
    pool.map(process, [i for i in range(len(scans))])

another_method()
```

By doing so, the object `scans` is not found in the local namespace of the function `process`, but it will be found in the global namespace. The argument parsing uses only integers and avoids complex objects that would require Pickle to be transferred to each process. That's at least how I understand the issue.