# Creating a pickle file when working with twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, pickle

I am trying to work with twitters API to retrieve some tweets, after which I want to perform very basic sentiment analysis on them

I have a limited number of requests per month so I don't want to waste a lot just setting up the code and playing around with it

I would like to cache the result from the API call so I am only making one request and then I can play around with the data I am getting

I have the following code to retrieve the data

```
try:
    with open('mycache.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        cache = pickle.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    cache = {}

@cachetools.cached(cache)
def create_call(yaml):
    with open('twitter_keys.yaml', 'w') as config_file:
        yaml.dump(config, config_file, default_flow_style=False)

    premium_search_args = load_credentials("twitter_keys.yaml",
                                           yaml_key="search_tweets_api",
                                           env_overwrite=False)

    rule = gen_rule_payload(SEARCH_QUERY,
                            results_per_call=RESULTS_PER_CALL,
                            )

    rs = ResultStream(rule_payload=rule,
                      max_results=MAX_RESULTS,
                      **premium_search_args)

    for tweet in rs.stream():
        return tweet

a = create_call(yaml)

with open('mycache.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(cache, f)
```

When I run this code I get a

```
TypeError: cannot pickle 'module' object
```

I've tried to 'convert' the return object to a dict or a string but as you can imagine that doesn't work

For transparency, I tried to just take the output of the first function and create a dict, as I thought that the dict would be treated like any other dict in the code

```
# added after the code to get the tweet
def get_json(tweet):
    x = dict(tweet)
    return x
```

Is there any way I could pickle module object being returned?

The other thing I could think of would be to store the values after running the code once but want to see if that can be avoided

Thanks!

Comment: What is the module that's getting cached?  Have you dumped the contents of "cache" in order to know what you are pickling?

Comment: Hmm, this is what I can see when I run the debugging code from 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790828/python-cant-pickle-module-objects-error

'  'fail': {
    (<module'yaml'from'/Users/myprofile/Documents/GitHub/PycharmProjectsOld/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py'>,
    ):'

Comment: So, `yaml` in your sample is a module (`import yaml`).  Why on earth do you pass it as a parameter?  That's not Pythonic.  Modules are global.